# There is no phonegap\.cordova\config.json

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, sencha-cmd

When I run `sencha app build -run native` I get this error:

```
[INF] [shellscript]    [error] ENOENT, open '''E:\asistantouch\phonegap\.cordova
\config.json'''
```

Why there is no `.cordova` folder? What should I write within the `config.json` file?

[image: phonegap cordova config.json]

Answer (score 1):

Hi there I manage to solve the issue creating that file with and empty object.

```
{}
```

like this link mention [fix](https://github.com/yarencheng/net.arenx.candidate.phonegap/commit/e71307c5b5ed6e20c2220b45b29124b1e03136d2)

Comment: can you run sencha cmd  in debug mode? `sencha -d app build ... `